# HTML Forms: Which Elements are Sent?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, serialization

I am trying to write a simple serialise function for HTML forms, and I *think* I know what data is sent from a form. However, this is only through experimentation:

- Only elements with `name`s
- Only `checked` radio buttons or checkboxes
- `select` items which have a selected value
- All other elements, including unknown ones
- Elements with the same `name` will each be sent individually; it’s up to the server to work out how to handle that

As regards `select`, if there is no `size` attribute, then an item is always selected item, while if there is a `size` attribute, then one will have to be selected.

The question is, is this correct? Where can I find the final word on this?

Thanks

Comment: you could read the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-form-element)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the link. I will comment further when I’ve finished looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

The w3.org spec refers to the form elements that are send during a submit action as 'Successful Controls'.

See here:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2

In particular, it lists the following rules on what to and not to send when a form is submitted.

- Controls that are disabled cannot be successful.
- If a form contains more than one submit button, only the activated submit button is successful.
- All "on" checkboxes may be successful.
- For radio buttons that share the same value of the name attribute, only the "on" radio button may be successful.
- For menus, the control name is provided by a SELECT element and values are provided by OPTION elements. Only selected options may be successful. When no options are selected, the control is not successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the server when the form is submitted.
- The current value of a file select is a list of one or more file names. Upon submission of the form, the contents of each file are submitted with the rest of the form data. The file contents are packaged according to the form's content type.
- The current value of an object control is determined by the object's implementation.
- Reset Buttons are not sent

It's worth mentioning that input elements with style display:none are not considered successful but visibility:hidden are.